# SwiftUI Preview pauses whenever I change a file

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-previews

I have a SwiftUI View (LandingScreenView.swift) that is using a button style implemented on another file (DefaultButtonStyle.swift). When I go to that Button Style file and change a line of code there, then return to the LandingScreenView.swift the SwiftUI preview has paused. It occurs always. This is a very fresh project with only those 2 files, I have one copy script on my build phases and I already set it to run "For install builds only". How can I make the SwiftUI works without pausing?

Xcode Version: 12.5

(I'm running it on an M1 MacBook, don't know if it makes any difference here)

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandingScreenView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer().frame(width: 0, height: 44, alignment: .center)
            Text("app.title")
                .font(.appTitle)
                .frame(minWidth: 0,
                       maxWidth: .infinity,
                       alignment: .center)
            
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Button("landing.login.button", action: {
                    
                })
                .buttonStyle(DefaultButton())

                Button("landing.about.button", action: {
                    
                })
                .buttonStyle(DefaultButton())
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
            
            Spacer()
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct LandingScreenView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LandingScreenView()
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct DefaultButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            configuration.label
                .padding()
                .frame(minWidth: 0,
                       maxWidth: .infinity,
                       minHeight: 44,
                       idealHeight: 44,
                       alignment: .center)
                
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(40)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Check Pods Manifest.lock]

EDIT:

My problem here is not that the preview has to recompile it every time. What seems a little bit weird is that I have to press the resume button every time I go out the screen and return.

[image]

Comment: This is by design. If you make a change elsewhere it has to "compile" again if you'd call it that. In order to update the view it will have to pause. Even if you run the live preview and make a change, it will not be reflected until you pause and run again.

Comment: I understand that it has to recompile, but, shouldn't it be automatic? What I'm saying is: I always have to press the "resume" button at the top right corner of the preview screen.

Comment: Yes this is by design. It should auto-resume if you make changes in the view you're working on, but if it's in a different file it will require you to build again.